# Connect BCS / BDC to the User Profile Service?

Tags: bcs, user-profile-service, bdc

Firstly I'm open to suggestions if people have better solutions or ideas. I would like to be able to create a list with a 'username' field that will pull additional fields from the information stored in the User Profile Service.

People picker columns do offer some of the information I want but not the users picture or other fields I would like to use. The other benefit of a BCS connection is that it will use the 'username' set in the first field and pull through other columns of information based on that first field. Additionally it would update when they or we update their profile.

Is it possible to connect to BCS to the information stored in the User Profile Service?

Thanks

Comment: Do you plan to use the additional fields for something, or is it just for an overview for your users?

Comment: In this instance it would be just for displaying to users a list of 'site contacts' With the site contacts information coming from the users profile and therefore kept up to date in one place.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the following: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89663/user-profile-multiple-data-sources/89673#89673

Comment: BTW, I do give an example of "no code" in my answer to that question.

Comment: (I didn't see this was old and updated by community...)

Answer (score 1):

If its just for a "list" of people, maybe it would be better to use people search.

Here is a link to a solution that maybe would fit your requirements: [How to: Create a Simple SharePoint 2010 People Directory](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-people-directory/)

It's a solution without use of code, just "standard" SharePoint.

Basically it just uses the OOTB search webpart with a predefined query.

Comment: Noticed now you wrote "Site Contacts", that wouldn't work that well with the above solution maybe if its based on only a subset of users.

Comment: Its a neat idea and one I could use in the future but due to the state of our AD and User Profiles it wouldn't return the correct results

Answer (score 0):

mtwelve,

Why do you want to create BCS connection... that doesn't makes sense! You can easily get all the information required from just People field, you will need LoginName... There is something called `UserProfileManager` and `UserProfile` objects under `Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles`

[How to: Retrieve a User Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms492435.aspx), and you can view all the [properties available for UserProfile here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147513.aspx)

You can get Picture of the user by PictureURL field and so on! and use them wherever you need!

Comment: The end game is for a 'Site Contacts' list that pulls the information from the users profile. With each field being pulled based on the chosen username for that item/row.

I would prefer to avoid a custom solution as I have no experience with Visual Studio and would ideally just create a list template.

Comment: And I am a developer/programmer :) always think about Visual Studio solution ;)..

Comment: As an example of why you might want to do this... I work for a joint venture and we use the AD from one of our parent companies. So the COO, the root of our org chart, has a manager in AD that he reports to. This means we have to use BCS to manage most of our HR related fields.